# Show that if $L$ is a nilpotent $n$-dimensional Lie algebra, then there is an ideal of dimension $n-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, ideals, nilpotence

This is my first question in the forum so I’m sorry for any mistake. $\ddot\smile$

I had a test in Lie algebras course and there was a question that asked for existence of ideal.

> Let $L$ be a lie algebra of dimension $n$ such that $L$ is nilpotent. Show that there exist an ideal $J$ of $L$ such that $\dim J = n-1$.

I’d tried to work with the definitions but I couldn’t find a way to prove the dimension of the ideal.

Comment: Can you use Engel's theorem?

Comment: Yes, but how can you use it here?

Comment: The proof of Engel's that I know contains a proof of your statement. Take $J$ to be any proper maximal subalgebra, consider $L$ as a $J$-module, by induction on dimension $L/J$ has an element that is mapped to $0$ by all $a\in J$. Conclude that exists $z \in L \setminus J$ such that $[z,J] \subset J$ and $\langle z \rangle \oplus J$ is a subalgebra. Since $J$ was maximal proper, conclude that $J$ is a codimension 1 ideal. Yet this may be an overkill, the answer by José Carlos Santos looks extremely simpler.

Comment: Do you know in which book can i find a full proof of Engle’s theorem In the way you wrote here?

Comment: Sure. "Fulton, Harris - Representation theory: a first course"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $L$ is nilpotent, $[L,L]\varsubsetneq L$. So, take any subspace $J$ of $L$ whose dimension is $n-1$ such that $[L,L]\subset J$ and then $J$ will be an ideal of $L$ whose dimension is $n-1$.